# How to capture the sender number in twilio sms "receive and reply to inbound sms" in .netcore?

Tags: c#, .net-core, twilio, twilio-api, twilio-programmable-chat

I'm testing out Twilio SMS and I faced a couple of issues. I'm trying to do an inbound SMS and send a reply to the user with the message body that the user sent.

```
        [HttpPost("Receive")]
    public TwiMLResult Receive()
    {
        var messagingResponse = new MessagingResponse();
        messagingResponse.Message("Hello to you too");

        return TwiML(messagingResponse);
    }
```

This is what I have done so far,
1. when I reply to the Twilio number I'm getting this message. How can I append the message the user sends into this message? Example: If the user sends "Hello", the respond message should be "Hello to you too and you said Hello"

2. I need to capture the sender's number to use later. How can I capture the number and if the answer is to add a statusCallback URL, How to add it here?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The request body from an inbound SMS has a POST form with fields for `from`, `to` and `body`.

So to get the senders number you could use this code:

```
var from = Request.Form["From"];
```

Other fields

```cs
var to = Request.Form["To"]; // your twilio number
var body = Request.Form["Body"]; // the message they sent
```

There is a more detailed example in [Twilio docs on conversations](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/tutorials/how-to-create-sms-conversations-csharp)

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what I'm looking for